# Django Github Hook

Tags: python, django, github, github-api

I am new in Django and github API. 
I've built project changelogs application using Django, user can add the project name, version, changelogs and etc.

I have plan that user who insert the project to my application, they can connect their project with their github repo.

So, when someone make a commit with tag `FEATURE` on their repo, it will automatically added in project's changelog.

I have no Idea to do that. 
I see this project https://github.com/sheppard/django-github-hook but it seems not as I want.

Is there any other references? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For working with github repos hooks, first you need an application waiting for github calls. Then setup a page to configure customers hook to notify when that happens.

Check [this](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/#receiving-webhooks) link for decription how to configure hooks and what is epected message from github side.

The remains tasks is on your hand :)